# Is it possible to make Flow validator check immutability-helper update syntax in reacts setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, flowtype

I'm using [flow](https://flow.org/) with Visual Studio Code integrated with  [vscode-flow-ide plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gcazaciuc.vscode-flow-ide) . Immutability update method comes from [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper). 
Is it possible to make Flow validator check ::update method syntax for errors with your type definition of state.

**Example:**

```
type State = {
    validTitle: boolean,
    post: {
        featured: boolean
    }
};
this.setState({
    validTitle: false,
    post: update(this.state.post, {
        featured: { $set: "" }
    })
});
```

Every simple state updates like "validTitle" property will be correctly validated but ::update method calls will be skipped due to it's declaration:

`update<any, never>(target: any, spec: Spec<any, never>): any`

**So my question is:**
Is there a way to force Flow to look for errors in update's method syntax and in my example find that "featured" property is being set invalid value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently there is no such way.

I've started to think about writing my own wrapper function to check types in the middle but then i realized that falling back to using `Object.assign` and spread operator for arrays `[...array]` is fair and easy enough for keeping state immutability.

And of course with this approach flow validator will inform you about incorrect value assignments.